# Javascript Regex: Replace under score and letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to create a efficient javascript regex to get the following result:

```
"first_name" => "firstName"
"user_address_id" => "userAddressId"
```

So i want to replace every underscore and the following character with the character in upper case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try something like this

```
var myString = 'first_name'
var camel = myString.replace(/_([a-z])/g, function (g) { return g[1].toUpperCase(); });
```

Answer (score 4):

Simply , replace `_(.{1})` with `\U\1\E`

`\U`turn upper every following char, then `\E` turns it off.

Comment: Do you have a complete example (line of javascript) ?

Comment: Sure, try this "first_name".replace(/_(.{1})/, function(match, $1){if($1) return $1.toUpperCase();});